# Specify which function to fold

Tags: vim, folding

Is it possible to specify which functions should be folded by vim automatically.

In Netbeans, there is something like

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="user-description">
  ...any code...
// </editor-fold>
```

Do you know about something similar I can use in vim?
When I close the vim I want folded functions to be folded again if I open the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a little different than what you're asking, because it doesn't deal with *semantic folding*, which NetBeans and other IDEs do.  However, storing a set of folds is normally done using the `:mkview` command, and you can automate this command and the `:loadview` command to make it transparent to you.  The details are in [this Vim wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_views_automatic).  I use one of the simpler versions in my vimrc, rather than the plugin, but both should work for what you need.